# Maximum map size in android using Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have full screen map in my Android application. I need to know maximum size of map.
we know there are lot of new devices with huge screens.
I know limit for static maps/640x640/, but I couldn't find maximal map size for Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation to map size, however loading time may increase for bigger maps because more tiles are loaded